# How to start CloudFoundry app using ReactorCloudFoundryClient?

Tags: java, cloud-foundry

I used `StartApplicationRequest` to create a sample request to start the application as given below:

```
StartApplicationRequest request = StartApplicationRequest.builder()
                .applicationId("test-app-name")
                .build();
```

Then, I used the `ReactorCloudFoundryClient` to start the application as shown below:

`cloudFoundryClient.applicationsV3().start(request);`

But my test application `test-app-name` is not getting started. I'm using latest Java CF client version (v4.5.0 RELEASE), but not seeing a way around to start the application.

Quite surprisingly, the [outdated version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-client-lib/1.1.3) seems to be working with the below code:

`cfstatus = cfClient.startApplication("test-app-name"); //start app`

`cfstatus = cfClient.stopApplication("test-app-name"); //stop app`

`cfstatus = cfClient.restartApplication("test-app-name"); //stop app`

I want to do the same with latest CF client library, but I don't see any useful reference. I referred to test cases written at CloudFoundry official Github repo. I derived to the below code after checking out a lot of docs:

```
StartApplicationRequest request = StartApplicationRequest.builder()
                    .applicationId("test-app-name")
                    .build();
```

`cloudFoundryClient.applicationsV3().start(request);`

Note that `cloudFoundryClient` is `ReactorCloudFoundryClient` instance as the latest library doesn't support the client class used with outdated code. I would like to do all operations (start/stop/restart) with latest library. The above code isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things here...

1. Using the reactor based client, your call to `cloudFoundryClient.applicationsV3().start(request)` returns a `Mono<StartApplicationResponse>`. That's not the actual response, it's the possibility of one. You need to do something to get the response. [See here for more details](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#mono).

   If you would like similar behavior to the original cf-java-client, you can call `.block()` on the `Mono<StartApplicationResponse>` and it will wait and turn into a response.

   Ex:

   ```
   client.applicationsV3()
       .start(StartApplicationRequest.builder()
                   .applicationId("test-app-name")
                   .build())
       .block()
   ```
2. The second thing is that it's `.applicationId` not `applicationName`. You need to pass in an application guid, not the name. As it is, you're going to get a 404 saying the application doesn't exist. You can use the client to fetch the guid, or you can use `CloudFoundryOperations` instead (see #3).
3. The [`CloudFoundryOperations` interface is a higher-level API](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client#cloudfoundryoperations-apis). It's easier to use, in general, and supports things like starting an app based on the name instead of the guid.

   Ex:

   ```
   ops.applications()
      .start(StartApplicationRequest.builder()
                .name("test-app-name").build())
      .block();
   ```

Comment: Hi Daniel. I wonder if you may not yet have had someone edit your posts to make them a bit less conversational. Stack Overflow is intended to be a repository of technical writing, and thus phrases like "hope that helps" tend to be discouraged and/or removed. I would not normally mention it, but you have over 200 of them. Would you mind refraining from adding these in the future? Thank you!

Comment: @halfer - I appreciate your perspective and feedback. I will take it into consideration. If I'm being honest, it's my way of trying to be friendly and add some humanity to my posts. If that's wrong, then I'm probably contributing knowledge to the wrong forum. I hope you can understand my perspective as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. There are several discussions on _Meta Stack Overflow_ that represent the community position. [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) is a good place to start, but there are many. My own view is that technical writing is not unfriendly _per se_, it is just succinct. People do not read an academic paper or an encyclopedia article and think of it as unfriendly - it is just an expected style for each medium.